# Set global "export to PDF" settings for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm an Aussie. Google Drive is obviously built for USA first. Each time I export a Google Sheets as a PDF, I have to change the page size from Letter to A4, and other such settings.

Is there a way to set the settings Globally?

Comment: This has been a requested feature for more than 3 years...
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/sMtzk-qnThs ...and Google are actively promoting their Apps to Australian Corporations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Google Sheets doesn't have a global setting for paper size, only Google Documents.

From the reference

> Note: Page setup is not available in Google Sheets.

## References

[Change the page setup of a document - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183618?hl=en)

Comment: Right. Thanks. I've sent feedback to the Google Sheets team. Fingers crossed!